# Code is not displaying database information from query

Tags: php, arrays, database, mysqli, mybb

I am trying to build a staff page, which quesries the MySQLi database holding registered users, and displays only moderators, admins, and super admins. This is the code I have. For some reason, nothing shows up in the table on the page. I have no fatal erros, so the code is "technically" correct, however the logic isn't outputting what I want.

The code below should query the database, fetch the row of info as an array, output the username and registration date into the table, and keep looping until there are now more rows left. Though, as I said, nothing is output. I have no idea what I am doing wrong.

If it makes a difference, this is a custom page in myBB forum software. I know the page is setup correctly because everything displays, except the info I am attempting to pull form the database.

```
<?php

global $headerinclude, $header, $theme, $footer, $lang;

if(!$mybb->user['uid'])
{
error_no_permission();
}

$lang->load('modcp');


$mysqli = new mysqli("XXXXXXXXX","XXXXXXXXXXX","XXXXXXXXX","XXXXXXXX");
$query_result = $mysqli->query("SELECT uid,username,usergroup,regdate FROM  mybb_users   ORDER BY regdate ASC");

if ($db->num_rows($query_result) > 0)
     {
     $usertablerows = "";

          while($users = mysqli_fetch_row($query_result))
          {
                if($users['usergroup'] != 3 || $users['usergroup'] != 4 || $users['usergroup'] != 6)
                {
                 $pass = "true";
                }
                else
                {
                       $staffuseruid = $users['uid'];
                       $rawregdate = $users['regdate'];
                       $usergroupvalue = $users['usergroup'];
                       $staffusername = $users['username'];

                       $staffuser = get_user($staffuserid);
                       $usertablerows .= ' <tr>
                      <td class="trow1">' . build_profile_link($staffusername, $staffuserid). '</tf>
                      <td class="trow2">' . my_date($mybb->settings['dateformat'], $rawregdate). '</td>
                      </tr>';
                }
          }
}

$template='<html>
<head>
<title>'.$pages['name'].'</title>
{$headerinclude}
</head>
<body>
{$header}
<table border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2" class="tborder">
<tr><td class="thead" colspan="4"><strong>The Staff</strong></td></tr>
<tr>
<td class="tcat"><span class="smalltext"><strong>Username</strong></span></td>
<td class="tcat"><span class="smalltext"><strong>Registered</strong></span></td>

</tr>
{$usertablerows}
</table>
{$footer}
</body>
</html>';
mysqli_close($mysqli);
$template=str_replace("\'", "'", addslashes($template));

add_breadcrumb($pages['name']);

eval("\$page=\"".$template."\";");

output_page($page);

?>
```

Comment: have you tried running the query directly in mysql console????

Comment: No, i never thought of that. I will try that right now.

Comment: The query pulls exactly what I need when done in phpMyAdmin

Answer (score 0):

You can check by appending database name to table name in mysql query.

Comment: That still doesnt solve the issue. When executing the query in phpMyAdmin it pulls exactly what i need. However, i cant get it from the database to the page displayed for whatever reason.

Comment: eval("\$page= \"$template\";"); Try this. I am not sure. But recheck eval function